# Hybrid Forward Lookup Zone

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, internal-dns

We have an active directory domain companyName.local (I know, not recommended), and a public domain companyName.com.  We have a mix of cloud servers and internally hosted servers.  What I would like to do is to have our DNS servers internally return the public address of our cloud servers and the internal address of our internally hosted servers.

I would like to not have to maintain both our public DNS records (NO-IP) and our internal records.

I was hoping there was a way create a zone that has our internal servers and all other servers get forwarded to our public DNS server.

I am sure I could do it by creating a new zone for each server (internal1.companyName.com) but I wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: `I would like to not have to maintain both our public DNS records (NO-IP) and our internal records` - In what sense? You do have to manage them both in order to create relevant records in both. I don't understand this statement. I also don't understand the problem. A request for server.companyname.local should be answered by the internal DNS server and a request for server.companyname.com should be answered by the external server, so what's the problem?

Comment: I can see how that was unclear.  What I don't want to do is every time we add a new cloud server to have to setup that cloud server in our public dns and then add a record in our private dns, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access "exampleServer.company.local I would:

1. Create the exampleServer.companyName.com A record in the public dns
2. Create the exampleServer.company.local A record (AD probably handles this?)
3. Set the [search domains](https://superuser.com/questions/184361/what-is-the-search-domains-field-for-in-the-tcp-ip-dns-settings-control-panel) to : company.local, companyName.com (in that order)
4. Access servers by only the local part of the hostname (EG: myWorkPC, exampleServer)

Comment: Not what I was looking for.  I want to use exampleServer.companyName.com both internally and externally so people with mobile devices (laptops, tablets, etc.) still can access it.  When they are in the office they get a 192.168.x.x address from DNS and when they are off network they get a public IP address.

Comment: if they can be trained to type "exampleServer" instead of "exampleServer.companyName.com" it will work as expected. Since that is unlikely in most cases, You will need to maintain a separate zone for public and private. Some of this can be scripted... But it's important to have someone around to maintain the scripts should any changes be needed.

Comment: This isn't for users to type in.  The server addresses are:
 1. Being stored inside application clients (git, etc.)
 2. The address is being configured in web servers as the address to return for link urls, etc.
 3. Some external users I have no control over their DNS search order and cannot add companyName.com to them.